# How to move cart in navigation section

Tags: magento2, cart, navigation

How to move cart in navigation section.Can any one help me thanks in advance.I try this code but does not work.

```
<move element="minicart" destination="navigation.sections" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After move minicart to navigation section you must add child element in phtml file

```
<move element="minicart" destination="navigation.sections" />
```

**Override** `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/sections.phtml` to your theme

**Copy sections.phtml to**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/sections.phtml

**Now add child element** in `sections.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart') ?>
```

Flush cache and try.

Comment: @MonuKumar, Welcome. Happy Coding...!